# angularjs nodejs npm install gives error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I have to use angularjs theme.

For this I download the source code from below URL :

https://startangular.com/product/flatlogic-angular-material-dashboard/

Perform installation Steps

```
install node-v6.9.2-x64.msi
E:\angular-material-dashboard-master>npm install
```

It gives the following error

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-material-dashboard@1.3.0 install: `bower install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-material-dashboard@1.3.0 install script 'bower install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-material-dashboard package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     bower install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-material-dashboard
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-material-dashboard
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\angular-material-dashboard-master\npm-debug.log
```

For the above error I try to run the following command

```
E:\angular-material-dashboard-master>npm install bower
```

It gives the following output

```
E:\angular-material-dashboard-master>npm install bower
angular-material-dashboard@1.3.0 E:\angular-material-dashboard-master
+-- bower@1.8.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jasmine-core@*
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY karma@>=0.10 <=0.13

npm WARN gulp-karma@0.0.5 requires a peer of karma@>=0.10 <=0.13 but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-jasmine@0.3.8 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-material-dashboard@1.3.0 No repository field.
npm WARN angular-material-dashboard@1.3.0 No license field.
```

Than again run the following error

```
E:\angular-material-dashboard-master>npm install
```

It gives the same error.

I am using Windows 10 and node-v6.9.2.

Comment: You should install the dependency as well.

Comment: @RandheerSinghChouhan which dependency I have to installed and how?

Comment: Since karma-jasmine 0.3.0 the jasmine library is no longer bundled with karma-jasmine and you have to install it on your own. You can simply do it by:

`$ npm install -g karma-jasmine `

Comment: @RandheerSinghChouhan You means I have to run command like this "C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install karma-jasmine@0.1.0 --save-dev" right?

Comment: yes e.g. 
`$ npm install -g karma-jasmine`

Comment: @RandheerSinghChouhan I mean, I have to run this command from "C:\Program Files\nodejs" or "E:\angular-material-dashboard-master" ?

Comment: yes you have to run this command using node and no need to specify the project url as it will be installed globally.

Comment: If it works then please let me know.

Comment: @RandheerSinghChouhan When I run "E:\angular-material-dashboard-master>npm install karma" output is "UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY karma@1.3.0
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN gulp-karma@0.0.5 requires a peer of karma@>=0.10 <=0.13 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-material-dashboard@1.3.0 No repository field."

Comment: @RandheerSinghChouhan Please help me how can I run this project. I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131583/discussion-between-randheer-singh-chouhan-and-user3441151).